# Unknown padding when using tablet simulator

Tags: ios, tablet

Why is there a black padding around when running on a tablet simulator? It works fine on iPhones, though.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made a small mistake. Your project's deployment device is set  to iPhone.  Just Go to your project's `General` tab and in `Deployment info` change device to **Universal**. Thats it.

[image]

Comment: Well, that was super embarrassing. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Latcie Same thing was happened with me in past :)

Answer (score 1):

It works in **iPhone-Mode**. You can use iPhone apps on iPad. It just scales to fill screen. If you want your app universal. You should make sure that your layouts work in Any,Any size class. And as @Bhavin Ramani answered, you should set it universal.